# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Variable Values are not updating

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image][image][image]I'm trying to update Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Variable Values but it is they are not updating.

Used In-line script PowerShell script.

Comment: Here you are assigning the value of $date to the variable 'time'. After setting it up can you try printing it, Write-Host $(time)

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan and Yes i tried as per below code and o/p is showing with empty.

$date=$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd");
echo $date
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=time]$date"
Write-Host $(time)

[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\b7162f51-142b-4cf3-8ed7-c9466c4dacf5.ps1'"
2022-12-21T10:33:06.8928944Z 2022_12_21
2022-12-21T10:33:06.9109664Z 
2022-12-21T10:33:07.0592608Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script

Answer (score 1):

1. In your script, you are trying to move the value to the `time` variable but you do not use it.
2. You can not use a new value of a pipeline variable in the same step through the pipeline variable reference. If you pass a new value with `Write-Host "##vso... myvar]$somevalue"` you may print it in some next build step: `Write-Host "$(myvar)"`

Check the documentation:

- [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch)
- [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)

Comment: Thanks for your info
Ex: 

1) I have one varibale called var1 and the value is "Demo1"

2) Stage(Dev)
   In this Stage i need to update the var1 value to "Demo2"
   This value i need to update in the variables places.
   
3) Stage (QA)
   From this stage i need to call the lastest value from var1 is ""Demo2
   
Is it possible to over the values in the One Stage to another stage ?

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, you can use that but only yaml supports this solution: [Set an output variable for use in future stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you could change the initial value of your variables during the pipeline running, I suppose that the variable value you defined in the ui could not be updated after finishing.

If you are going to pass the variables between stages, I suppose that you could refer to [output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages).

**Update on 1/2**

=========================================

After more tests, i realized that stages of release pipelines are run on different agents, and output variables could not be a good choice for you.

If you are going to pass and update the value of your variable between different stages, I suppose that ***yaml*** could be the better choice instead of release pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your info
Ex: 

1) I have one varibale called var1 and the value is "Demo1"

2) Stage(Dev)
   In this Stage i need to update the var1 value to "Demo2"
   This value i need to update in the variables places.
   
3) Stage (QA)
   From this stage i need to call the lastest value from var1 is ""Demo2
   
Is it possible to over the values in the One Stage to another stage ?